# How can I quickly create a row per day per unique identifier?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm relatively new to SQL having come from a SAS background. I feel like there is a really simply solution to this...

I've got two tables - a date dimension and a table that contains three columns - customer number, date and an event flag.

I want to build a data set that generates a full 365 day history for each customer.

So, for example my event table has this

```
CustomerNumber - Date - Event
12345   24/02/2019    1
12345   28/02/2019    1
```

I want a table that does this;

```
CustomerNumber - Date - Event
12345   24/02/2019   1
12345   25/02/2019   0
12345   26/02/2019   0
12345   27/02/2019   0
12345   28/02/2019   1
```

When I join to the date dimension I can easily get the date and event column to show correctly but I will get a NULL in the CustomerNumber field where there was no record in the event table.

My need for retaining customer number is so that I can run windowed 30 day running totals for each unique customer on a daily basis.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138672/fill-in-missing-dates-with-data-value-from-previous-populated-date-for-group

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cross join` and `left join`:

```
select c.customernumber, d.date,
       coalesce(t2.event, 0) as event
from dates d cross join
     (select distinct customernumber from table2) c left join
     table2 t2
     on t2.date = d.date and t2.customernumber = c.customernumber;
```

You can add a `where` clause to filter on `d.date` for a particular time period.

Comment: Thank you Gordon this worked a treat. I will get reading up on Cross Join